# how to pass variable as the $_POST on php

Tags: php, variables, post, input

My code is don't runnig. how to pass variable as the $_POST on php . Or is it not possible?

original code

```
foreach ($ret[0]->trends as $topic) {
                            $a = $topic->name;
                            $a = preg_replace("'", " ", $a);
                            $i++;
                                  echo "
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class='hidden-xs'>$i</td>
                                      <td>$topic->name</td>
                                      <td><form role='form' action='/trgy/follow.php' method='get'>
                                      <input type='text' name='$a' placeholder='follow number' >
                                      <input type='submit' value='Follow'></form>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>";

                                  $count = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$a]);
                                  if (!empty($_GET[$topic->name])) {
                                    $ret1 = $topic->name;
                                    $lasttweets = $connectionOauth->get('search/tweets', array('q' => $ret1, 'count' => $count));

                                }
                              }
```

don't run - this Problematic lines - I can not count

```
$a = $topic->name;
<input type='text' name='$a' placeholder='Number' >
$count = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$a]);
```

Comment: What's that code ? PHP or HTML ? In both cases here are the <?php ?> tags ?

Comment: use php tag and form

Comment: It is possible if you use the right markup.

Comment: yes. html and php

Answer (score 1):

You have to use html and php.one of the powerful features of PHP is the way it handles HTML forms. You should declare Variable inside php tag.When the user fills out the form above and clicks the submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file.To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables inside a php tag.

```
<?php
    $a = $variable;
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form1">
    <input type='text' name='<?php echo $a ?>' placeholder='Number' >
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit"
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
    $count = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$a]);
echo $count;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: @omer form method is get . then how you use post?

Comment: @omer user  $count = htmlspecialchars($_GET[$a]);

Answer (score 0):

your are running variables inside a text echo if you want to echo text and variables your should close the text and join the variable then reopen then text
example.

```
echo "<TD> this is my variable </TD> 
      <TD>".$variable."</TD>" ;
```

and if you want to post multiple items you can use i$ input name []

```
<input type="text" name="a[]">
```

then count your post like this and $i will be the number that you want starting at 0

```
$count = count($_POST["a"]);
$b=($_POST["a"][$i]);
```